# How to resolve problem with gatsby-source-graphql

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I tried to connect `gatsby-source-graphql` with my gatsby JS project. But I have error 
`Cannot query field "alladventures" on type "Query"`.

This is my gatsby-config code with my API:
https://api.services.activelyme.com/graphql/playground

```
      resolve: `gatsby-source-graphql`,
      options: {
        // This type will contain remote schema Query type
        typeName: `ALLADVENTURES`,
        // This is the field under which it's accessible
        fieldName: `alladventures`,
        // URL to query from
        url: `https://api.services.activelyme.com/graphql`,
      },
    },
```

This is my component code

```
    graphql`
      query {
        alladventures {
          adventures {
            title
          }
        }
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author
            norwayItems {
              item {
                status {
                  category
                  date
                  season
                }
                title
                location
                userName
                description1
                dates
                show {
                  regular_price
                  promotional_price
                }
                rating {
                  stars
                  review
                  adventures
                }
                mainImage
                guideImage
                link
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
```

```
Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named "Query".

Error: Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named "Query".
```

I have to show adventures. But I get error each time.

If I use this example with this API everything works very well
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/third-party-graphql/